# TintColor for UIImageVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c

Добрый день! Проблема с `UIImageView`, а точнее со сменой tintColor через `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. Цвет меняется правильно, но если я поставлю другую картинку, tintcolor сбрасывается. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо!

```
- (void)setButtonsImageColor:(UIColor *)buttonsImageColor
{
    for (JTAlertButton *button in self.buttons)
    {
        button.imageView.image = [button.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [button.imageView setTintColor:buttonsImageColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Он меняется через UIAppearance, или же через `[button.imageView setTintColor:buttonsImageColor];`? Зачем оно в коде?

Answer (score 1):

После подстановки нового изображения нужно снова вызвать этот метод.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?